# Using Jquery with React (FlipClock)

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, dependencies

I have created a react app from create-react-app.
And now i want to use jquery FlipClock plugin to simple render a flipping clock (nothing else).

package.json

```
{
       "name": "flip-clock",
       "version": "0.1.0",
       "private": true,
       "dependencies": {
       "flipclock": "^0.8.2",
       "react": "^16.3.2",
       "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
       "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
       "start": "react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import FlipClock from 'flipclock'

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    $('.App').FlipClock(3600 * 24 * 3,{clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true
  });
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(){
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am getting **jQuery is not defined**(flipcopy.js) ref error[image: ERRORS] and various other error (which make no sense to me).

What i am speculating is that somehow flipcopy.js is not able to resolve its jquery dependencies from its npm module.
Thanks in advance

Comment: flipclock has no idea that you have bundled jQuery into your webpack bundle. You need to add jQuery the usual way, as `<script>` in your public index.html.

Comment: @ChrisG I am getting confused here, if jquery is in the bundle.js then it should  be available to flipclock as well.
I tried putting it in script. Now i am getting a new error `FlipClock() is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Use Webpack's [provide plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) to shim the global variable that the plugin expects, mapping it to your installed npm:jquery.

```
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      jQuery: 'jquery' // provide a global named jQuery loading it as the export from the module 'jquery'
    }),
    // etc.
  ],
  // etc. 
};
```

Then change your import to better reflect its semantics

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'flipclock';

class App extends React.Component {...}
```

Since you never consume flipclock's default export, assuming it even has one, but rather imported because of the side effect it has on jQuery you should use the important style above which is designed for that purpose. This is clearer and also will not break when optimizers attempt to treeshake unused imports.

Ideally, we wouldn't have any global, but whether we need one or not depends on flipclock's use of jquery. Tools like SystemJS can work around this.

Comment: i think this will work but i want to know whats the reason why simple imports doesn't work. setting the window objects parameter to $ works.
But then jQuery is undefined in flipcopy.js

Comment: What are simple imports?

Comment: if i use `import $ form 'jquery'` the local $ reference is resolved but it fails to get in flipcopy.js

Comment: That is expected. That is how JavaScript's scoping works (and the same is true of most languages). When you `import $ from 'jquery'` what do you think the scope of `$` is?

Comment: yeah i agree, its scope should be App.js. But even if set the window.jQuery = $ in App.js, it is not found in flipClock.js

Comment: Now I see what you are wondering about. The `import` dependencies of an ES Module are all statically evaluated and resolved before the module itself is loaded. So flipclock is loaded before you mutate `window`

Comment: ohh .. i see, makes sense. but is there any other way to resolve jQuery statically?

Comment: It is being resolved statically. I really don't recommend that you use jQuery as a global. It doesn't benefit you at all. It does make your code harder to maintain and harder for to interoperate with other libraries. If you're going to use modules, use modules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169776/discussion-between-zealvault-and-aluan-haddad).

Comment: The documentation for the webpack plugin should make it clear how to do what you want but I have not the slightest interest in teaching you, step by step, how to do things wrong, how to write bad code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use jQuery, you can do two things....

1. Explicitly `npm install` it, so that it shows in your package.json.
2. Include it in your html file as a normal script, as Chris G mentioned.

If you go the second route, then you will need to do something like this before you reference it inside your `componentDidMount()` method.

```
const $ = window.$; 
$('.App').(do_some_stuff);
```

Comment: why i have to take reference the global jquery when i have imported jquery from node_module

Comment: i have installed it through npm in the first place and it is very well present in my package.json